# Why, in a classification task, with $n$ input variables, we can obtain all $2^n$ classiﬁcation functions for each possible set of missing inputs?

Tags: combinatorics, functions

I don't get why, for a classification task with missing values, **With $n$ input variables, we can obtain all $2^n$ diﬀerent classiﬁcation functions needed for each possible set of missing inputs,**.

> *Classiﬁcation becomes more challenging if the computer program is not
> guaranteed that every measurement inits input vector will always be
> provided. To solve the classiﬁcation task, thelearning algorithm only
> has to deﬁne a single function mapping from a vectorinput to a
> categorical output. When some of the inputs may be missing,rather than
> providing a single classiﬁcation function, the learning algorithm ˜must
> learn a set of functions. Each function corresponds to
> classifying with diﬀerent subset of its inputs missing. This kind of
> situation arises frequently in medical diagnosis because many kinds of
> medical tests are expensive or invasive. One way to eﬃciently deﬁne
> such a large set of functions is to learn a probability distribution
> over all the relevant variables, then solve the theclassiﬁcation task by
> marginalizing out the missing variables. **With $n$ input variables, we can now obtain all $2^n$ diﬀerent classiﬁcation functions needed for each possible set of missing inputs,** but the computer program needs to learn only a single function describing the joint probability distribution for an example of a deep probabilistic model applied to such a task in this way.* - Goodfelloz et al., [*Deep Learning*, chapter 5](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/ml.html)

Indded, I get that each variable offers either Classification A/Classification B output, and that we have n variables so that we have $\overbrace{2\times 2\times ... \times 2}^{n \ times}$ possible outpus. But that doesn't make functions, does it?

I am a slow learner in mathematics, don't hesitate to explain it to me with dummy examples or graphs :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What that Author is trying to state is not what you got out of it.

Let us say we have Medical Data like Blood Pressure , Sugar level , heart rate ,  height , weight & age ( $6$ Inputs ) where we have to make a Single Decision ( not $2^6$ Decisions ) whether to send the Patient to a Doctor or not.

The **Single Output** is either "Send to Doctor" or "Not Necessary to Send to Doctor" ( $2$ values , not $2^6$ values) which is a Binary Classification.

We can make a Binary Classifier for this :
$D_1( Blood Pressure , Sugar level , heart rate , height , weight , age )$

**The Problem which the Author is highlighting is that , we may not have all 6 Inputs available.**

Then we require more Single Decision Classifiers or functions :
$D_2( Blood Pressure , heart rate , height , weight , age )$
$D_3( Blood Pressure , Sugar level , height , weight , age )$
$D_4( Blood Pressure , height , weight , age )$
$D_5( Blood Pressure , Sugar level , heart rate , height , weight )$

Each of these will have certain missing Inputs.

In the **Extreme Case** , we may want around $2^6$ such Single Decision Classifiers or functions !

Thus our algorithm should generate all such Single Decision Binary Classifiers or Single Decision Binary functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Prem! Yet, why is it $2^6$ Single Decision Classifiers or functions rather than $6!$? To my mind we ma have one classifier with all variables, 6with one missing, 6*6 with two missing ...

Comment: Each Input may or may not be missing , which is '$2$' Possibilities , hence '$2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times \cdots 2$' , which gives '$2^n$' , when having '$n$' Inputs , @RevolucionforMonica